# how can I get session statistics for ended video session

Tags: opentok, tokbox

Is there a way to get session statistics for a session. I am looking to see if I can query information like

1. Session Duration
2. Session Quality
3. Did video and audio work?

Comment: Can you post code on what you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

Check out OpenTok Archiving [here](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/). With this, you can record, save, and retrieve OpenTok sessions.

> You create an archive for an OpenTok session using the [OpenTok REST API](https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/) or one of the [OpenTok Server SDKs.](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/server/) When you create an archive, the recording starts. You can only create an archive for sessions that have at least one client connected. (A client must start publishing a stream within one minute or the archive stops.)
>
> As clients start and stop publishing streams, the streams are recorded.

Hope it helps
!

Comment: I am currently not archiving the sessions. Can I get the statistics without archiving?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but I don't know everything. It would seem overly complicated to write a script for a service OpenTok already provides.. Besides, once you got the data, I would assume you would want to track it, or store it.

Answer (score 0):

https://tokbox.com/developer/tools/inspector/
Has an inspector tool where you can retrieve information for a given session.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late for the original poster who asked this question, but since it's a top hit for queries on tokbox and stats, this might be useful to others who wish to gather data for their own monitoring systems (in addition to the web based session inspector URL the original poster found.):

https://www.tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#getStats

This is a *client side* function, not server side. Calling getStats() on an existing session will give you information on packet loss, etc up to the point in time it's invoked. I'm not sure whether it's safe to call during a session teardown when a call ends; or if you need to regularly poll it for information (every second?), and post the latest data to your server when you detect the session ending (via streamEvent.)

Keep in mind this only gives data on the *received* audio and video for a given client; not what is *sent* to other users.